# Glomming to make a sh script

Tags: shell, zsh

Is this a stupid thing to do?

- pipe output of ls -1 to a file
- edit the file to surround each line with quote characters
- and add a command at front of each line
- make the file executable
- run it as a script

I ask because the files swept up in ls -1 have special characters like parentheses, back quotes, etc. My editor macro surrounds each filename with double-quotes, but that's not enough.

Is there a more righteous way to do this? Should I be glomming within the script itself? I like using the editing step to catch errors, but I may just be being stubborn,

(Context: I have thousands of MP3 files and want to run a program on each to get its tempo.)

What's the smart thing to do here?

Comment: Its fine, everyone does automation using some scripts (quick & dirty way) and most of the time its used only you. 
i think only one line of command is enough
- `find ~/Music/ -iname *.mp3 -type f -exec du -h {} \;`
replace`du -h` with your command. I highly recommend reading docs/tutorials on `find` & `xargs` command before further move.

Comment: if you want execute more that one command use this.
`for music in ~/Music/*.mp3; do  du -h  "$music" ; done`
its  just a `for` loop

Comment: You should read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: The Wiki page Shawn linked definitively led me to believe: "Yes, Steve indeed wants to do a stupid thing." Since I cannot be sure ls will output something that can be safely/reliably parsed, I ought not rely upon ls to make a list of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this on your command line

```sh
for file in *; do mycommand "$file"; done
```

replacing `mycommand` with whatever command you want to run.

More info: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html

Answer (score -1):

My answer, is definitely, "YES."

Filenames can include special characters that, if present, can lead astray even the cleverest text parsing algorithm. Instead of getting a list of files to process from ls, there are several alternatives (shown in comments and answers above) that do not need parsing. Hence, it is stupid to pipe ls output to a file as described in my question!

Comment: To what question are you saying "Yes"? Also, this is not a useful, actionable answer. It does not solve the OP's problem.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to do a stupid thing! As the OP I happen to know what I was after, a reliable way to get a list of files matching some pattern. And I was disabused of the notion that "ls" will give me something I can parse into that list.